# Supported AVCaptureSessionPreset on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

Is there a way to check whether is concrete AVCaptureSessionPreset supported on iOS device? I want to set a resolution of AVCaptureSession, but I do not know how to check whether the divice is capable to capture camera frames using selected resolution.

```all
AVCaptureSession * _session;
NSString * _sessionPreset;
_sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;

// Here I would like to perform a check.

[_session setSessionPreset:_sessionPreset];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this:

```
if ([self.captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080])
    {
        self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
    } else if ([self.captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480])
        {
            NSLog(@"Set preview port to 640X480");
            self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
        }
```